# How to make an observable share across subscribers in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Consider the following code

```
getObservable() {
    return this.http.get('get_something').map(
        data => {
            return true;
        },
        err => {
            return false;
        }
    );
}

subscriber_1 = this.getObservable().subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log("from subscriber 1", data);
    }
);

subscriber_2 = this.getObservable().subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log("from subsriber 2", data);
    }
);

for (var _i = 0; _i < 100; _i++) {
    this.getObservable()
}
```

I expect `from subscriber 1` and `from subsriber 2` to get print `100` times. However it is only printed `1` time.

I thought observables are vectors and not scalars, so that anytime the same observable is invoke it will invoke all subscribers?

I must be doing something wrong.

Can someone help out?

Thanks

Comment: You're calling your request in your return statement twice, since you're calling your function twice. You should make a member of your class typed as a `*Subject` instead, tgen you can sunscribe to it, and then push values to it to notify the observers.

Comment: can you show a screen shot of your console output? (just wanted to make sure you are not seeing the 'count' increase within the output as 'bubble' on the same line when one output is being repeated in console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you do:

1. You create a function which creates a request and returns some value.
2. The first subscriber `subscriber_1` is making the request and when you call the subscribe function is waiting only for the current request to receive a response.
3. When you do the loop you are just making a request. You are not doing anything to handle the response to these requests.

So far from what I understand you want to use a `Subject` from RxJS.

```
let subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

// Anytime the subject value is changed a notification is triggered 
// The subscribe function is handling it 
let subscriber_1 = subject.AsObservable().subcribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  return data;
})

// Trigger a notification 100 times
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   subject.next(i);
}
```

Here is an one good article where you can understand more about `Subject` class https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

Or

If you don't want to use a RxJS you have to implement an observable pattern.

http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/observer-design-pattern Here is one good explanation with an example.